# Validate Numbers Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written the code so far and came up with this. I have to

Make sure the user input numbers into the text boxes and I was given errors using the Xhtml format, one, the '&&' sign gave me errors and due to online help, I was told I needed to use //

As I student learning Javascript I have no idea what this is or means, but as I placed it there, I was given more errors and my code crashed up after the javascript was added.

Thanks for the help in advance

```
    <head>
           <script type = 'text/javascript'>
             //  <![CDATA[
   $('#submit').click(function(){
validateRange();
validateRa();    
})

 function validateRange() {
        var txtVal = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
 var txtVal1=parseInt(txtVal);
        if (txtVal1 >= 3000 && txtVal1 <= 3999) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Please enter a number between 3000-3999');
            return false;
        }
    }

     function validateRa() {
        var txtVal1 = document.getElementById("AcctNo").value;
         var txtVal2=parseInt(txtVal1);

        if (txtVal2 >= 90000 && txtVal2 <= 99999) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Please enter a number between 90000-99999');
            return false;
        }
}
     // ]]
</script>
        <title>Account Lookup</title>


    </head>
    <body>
       <h1> Please Provide Your Information</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="AcctNo" value="Account Number"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="CustomerID" value="CustomerID" onchange="validateRange()"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="Type" value="Account Type" onchange="validateRange()"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="balance" value="Balance"/></p>


    <p class="submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" id="submit" /><button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button></p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what are your error(s)?

Comment: error on line 41 at column 38: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: This is a jsfiddle of your code and it gives no errors. The only change I made was `<p class="submit" />` to `<p class="submit">` http://jsfiddle.net/7q546nzn/

Comment: but he is not using this class.he is having error as he has not closed the curly braces for the second method.

Comment: I copy pasted from the question.

Comment: Reset and submit buttons with no related form do nothing, you should use plain buttons. In an HTML document, the markup `<p class="submit" />` is seen as `<p class="submit">`.

Comment: The other stuff is a empty form of what my teacher has asked me for. Also it's a she** girls take programming too.
I edited the code and I still have errors: error on line 31 at column 30: xmlParseEntityRef: no name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**
try using this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#submit').click(function(){
       validateRange();
validateRa();    
});
});
 function validateRange() {
        var txtVal = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
 var txtVal1=parseInt(txtVal);
        if (txtVal1 >= 3000 && txtVal1 <= 3999) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Please enter a number between 3000-3999');
            return false;
        }
    }

     function validateRa() {
        var txtVal1 = document.getElementById("AcctNo").value;
         var txtVal2=parseInt(txtVal1);

        if (txtVal2 >= 90000 && txtVal2 <= 99999) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Please enter a number between 90000-99999');
            return false;
        }
     }

</script>
<html>

<title>Account Lookup</title>

    <body>
       <h1> Please Provide Your Information</h1>
    <p><input type="text" id="AcctNo" value="Account Number"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="CustomerID" value="CustomerID" onchange="validateRange()"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="Type" value="Account Type" onchange="validateRange()"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="balance" value="Balance" /></p>


    <p class="submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" id="submit" /><button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button></p>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: if (txtVal1 >= 3000 && txtVal1 <= 3999) this line gives me errors still

Comment: I did, but now the input type submit button says input type will not work in body

Comment: it is working for me but still i am changing it see after updation.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I closed the <p class="submit" /> when it should be <p class="submit" > or at least its working now

Answer (score -1):

BTW the function validateRa missing the closing curly braces you need to add } before  // ]]

```
function validateRa() {
    var txtVal1 = document.getElementById("AcctNo").value;
     var txtVal2=parseInt(txtVal1);

    if (txtVal2 >= 90000 && txtVal2 <= 99999) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Please enter a number between 90000-99999');
        return false;
    }
}   //<= this is missing in your code
// ]]
```